# curl output to csv table

Tags: bash, web-scraping, curl

I have a bash code that generates an output that is currently saved in a .txt file. I'm trying to instead place these data points in a csv table. Can you help me with this?

The sample output looks like this:

```
****** A Day at the Races ******
     * 19371937
     * PassedPassed
     * 1h 51m
IMDb RATING
7.5/10
14K
****** The King and the Chorus Girl ******
    * 19371937
    * ApprovedApproved
    * 1h 34m
IMDb RATING
6.2/10
376
****** Room Service ******
    * 19381938
    * ApprovedApproved
    * 1h 18m
IMDb RATING
6.6/10
5.2K
****** At the Circus ******
    * 19391939
    * PassedPassed
    * 1h 27m
IMDb RATING
6.8/10
6K
```

I'm trying to change this into a csv that contains: Movie title, year of release, notes, run time, imdb rating and number of reviews as columns.

for example, for the first datapoint above, the csv datapoint should
look like:

```
Movie title: 'A day at the races'
Year of release: 1937
Notes: Passed
Run time: 1h 51m
IMDB rating: 7.5/10
Number of reviews: 14k
```

The code used for generating the above output:

```
#!/bin/bash

# fullname="USER INPUT"
read -p "Enter fullname: " fullname

if [ "$fullname" = "Charlie Chaplin" ]; then
  code="nm0000122"
else
  code="nm0000050"
fi

rm -f imdb_links.txt

curl "https://www.imdb.com/name/$code/#actor" |
  grep -Eo 'href="/title/[^"]*' |
  sed 's#^href="#https://www.imdb.com#g' |
  sort -u |
while read link; do
   # uncomment the next line to save links into file:
   #echo "$link" >>imdb_links.txt

   curl "$link" |
     html2text -utf8 |
     sed -n '/Sign_In/,/YOUR RATING/ p' |
     sed -n '$d; /^\*\{6\}.*\*\{6\}$/,$ p'
done >imdb_all.txt
```

Comment: This format looks like it can be parsed fairly reliably. However are you sure the API can't provide the same data in a more structured/common format, such as JSON?

Comment: I just saw you are using IMDB, which I believe has a free tier API.

Comment: @dan, I was not allowed to use their API for this assignment unfortunately. Hence, making use of this method

Comment: Well, each record is seven lines. So assuming that is consistent, you can map the line number to the appropriate header (ie. every 7th line after line 1 is the film title). That's where I'd start. Also you should clarify output format - commas between field, and one row per movie (csv)? Or a "key: value" list like your example output?